# Setting a background image in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jtabbedpane

I want to set a background image in a simple JTabbedPane. I used a Jlabel to set my background image.  But i haven't been able to do so as i get a null pointer exception upon running. 
Can anyone help with some more ideas?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class ImageTest 
{
 JTabbedPane tp;
 JLabel lab1
 JPanel  welcome;
 JFrame frame;
 ImageIcon image2;
 public void createUI()
 {
    frame=new JFrame("JTabbedPane");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    welcome= new JPanel(null);
    welcome.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1366,786));
    image2 = new ImageIcon("icloud.jpg");
    tp=new JTabbedPane();
            Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
    pane.add(tp);
    tp.addTab("Welcome", welcome);

    lab1.setIcon(image2);
    lab1.setBounds(0,0,1500,700);

    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("I-Cloud");

}   
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    ImageTest  tbp = new ImageTest ();
    tbp.createUI();     
}
   }
```

EDIT:

```
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
 import javax.swing.UIManager;
 import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
 import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 class ImageTest 
  {
 JTabbedPane tp;
 JLabel lab1;
 JPanel  welcome,w;
 JFrame frame;
 ImageIcon image2;
 JButton b1;

public void createUI()
{
    frame=new JFrame("JTabbedPane Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    b1=new JButton();
    welcome= new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1,15,15));
    w=new JPanel (new GridLayout(1, 1, 15, 15));
    welcome.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1366,786));

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageTest.class.getResource("icloud.jpg"));

    tp=new JTabbedPane();
            Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
    pane.add(tp);


    lab1=new JLabel();
    lab1.setIcon(icon);
    w.setOpaque(false);
    w.add(b1);


    b1.setVisible(true);
            welcome.add(lab1);
            welcome.add(w);
            tp.addTab("Welcome", welcome);

    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("I-Cloud");

}   
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

        ImageTest w = new ImageTest();
        w.createUI();   

    }
  }
```

Comment: What line throws the NPE?

Comment: `ImageIcon` expects the `String` to represent a file.  If the image is embedded or stored elsewhere, `ImageIcon` my return a `null` `Image`

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels- the lines  lab1.setIcon(image2);  and    tbp.createUI();  show NPE.

Comment: @MadProgrammer- the image file is in the folder created for this project in My eclipse.

Comment: @user3320152 : Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230) for how to add images to Java Project. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may just want to paint the image onto the panel you use for the `JTabbedPane` (as seen below). But as MadProgammer pointed out. It's most likely you are getting a null from the file location of your image file.

Note: when passing a String to the `ImageIcon` you are telling it to look for image in the file system. though this may work in a development environment from your IDE, it will not work at time of deployment Instead of reading the image file from the file system, you want to load it from the class path, as should be don with [**embedded resources**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info), using a URL, which can be obtained by using `MyClass.class.getResource(path)`

So the way you should loading your image is like this

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageTest.class.getResource("icloud.jpg"));
```

And your image file would be in the same package as `ImageIcon.java`. You don't *have* to put the image in the same package, as you can specify a different path. You can find more info from the embedded resource tag wiki link above.

But back to the option of painting the background, see the example below. Instead of using a URL web link for the image though, you would read in your image file path as specified above.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TabBackground {

    private BufferedImage bg;

    public TabBackground() {
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-wWANHD-Dr00/TtSmeY57ZXI/AAAAAAAABB8/t-fpXmQZ0-Y/s1600/Vector_by_Karpiu23.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TabBackground.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 300);
            }
        };
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1, 15, 15));
        buttons.setOpaque(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            buttons.add(new JButton("Button"));
        }
        tabPanel.add(buttons);

        JTabbedPane tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabPane.add("Panel with Bachground", tabPanel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tabbed Pane with Background");
        frame.setContentPane(tabPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(TabBackground.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                new TabBackground();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @peeskillet- I am still getting exception in the line ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageTest.class.getResource("icloud.jpg"));

Comment: Put your image in the same package as the `ImageTest.java`

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Does it has to do anything with image resolution?

Comment: It has a NPE exception.

Comment: If it's that line the NPE is pointing to. The _only_ thing it could be is that your path is wrong. If the image is in the same package as the class the you are just using `"icloud.jpg"` and the image is actually named `icloud.jpg`, you shouldnt get an NPE on that line

Comment: But even if the image isn't present at all it shouldn't generate a NPE.

Comment: I knew it. The IMmageIcon code you provided will _never_ throw an NPE. that wasnt even the line that was throwing the NPE. it the next line in the code from your post where you try and set the icon for your label. You never inititialized your label. Thats where the NPE is coming from. a null label.

Comment: You can't do anything with a component that hasn't been initialized

Comment: `lab1 = new JLabel();
        lab1.setIcon(image2);`

Comment: user3313050 has already made this one work and has posted this with a picture. I don't know what's wrong in mine.

Comment: You never added the label to the panel. Do follow my answer, You will have better luck with adding components on top of the image. Don't expect that just because you add the label, that will be the background. Doesn't work like that. If you paint the image on the panel, you can still add components on top of the image. That's why I suggested it. If there's something you dont understand about my code, just ask

Comment: Another thing you can do is just add the label to the tab, without the panel, set the layout manager for the label, then add component to the label.

Comment: Hello! Finally i got my image set. But i can't set the location and size of the button like the example you had shown. i have edited my code. plz help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an image like this on Jframe:

```
tp.addTab("Welcome",new JLabel(new ImageIcon("bksqla_xlargecover.jpg")));
```

[image]

Comment: I'd add, you need to make sure that you specify a layout manager for the label as its spade fault layout manages is null

Comment: It always shows a NPE exception. I tried everything. Does it has to do  anything with image resolution?